# unicode is not defined error - flask-flatpages and python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-flatpages

I installed `Flask-FlatPages` and am trying to run this simple app (to display `.md` files):

```
import sys
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_flatpages import FlatPages, pygments_style_defs

DEBUG = True
FLATPAGES_AUTO_RELOAD = DEBUG
FLATPAGES_EXTENSION = '.md'
FLATPAGES_ROOT = 'content'
POST_DIR = 'posts'

app = Flask(__name__)
flatpages = FlatPages(app)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route("/posts/")
def posts():
    posts = [p for p in flatpages if p.path.startswith(POST_DIR)]
    posts.sort(key=lambda item:item['date'], reverse=False)
    return render_template('posts.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/posts/<name>/')
def post(name):
    path = '{}/{}'.format(POST_DIR, name)
    post = flatpages.get_or_404(path)
    return render_template('post.html', post=post)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Whenever I run the app, I get this error:

> NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

The trackback (flask-flatpages) is this:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_flatpages/__init__.py", line 290, in _pages
_walk(unicode(self.root))
```

I know `unicode` is now `str` in Python 3 -- can I fix the issue from my app (without modifying the package)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if the package does not support Python 3, then you cannot easily make it work. You can wait for support or find alternative package. If the only problem is missing definition for `unicode`, then it can be monkeypathed like

```
import builtins
builtins.unicode = str
```

before importing `flask_flatpages`. But I doubt missing `unicode` is the only problem.

Comment: Hmm... that took care of the issue but I run into other problems like `Str has no attribute decode()`. Your solution solved this problem though. Thanks!